# Image very squashed - ASP.NET and Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

No matter how I try to fiddle with the HTML, my image shown below in my ASP.NET page (using Bootstrap) is very squashed and small. It's meant to be 279px by 65px but it ends up much smaller than that. what am I doing wrong? I can't get it to render at its normal size whether i use responsive image tags, don't, specify width and height or don't etc.  Help!?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img src="/Content/Priceline.Cloud_Big.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="279" height="65">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>This website can be used to attach new log files to Cloud Capture monitoring, or review existing log file data captured from our retail network.</p>
        <p>To access the menu, please click the Open Administration Menu button</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you attach a image for better understanding?

Comment: Sure. Here is the image: https://i.imgur.com/ZCFWDMg.png and here is what it looks like rendered https://i.imgur.com/ywlWMLD.png

Comment: try inspecting image then go to computed and edit height and width there and see if its work?

Comment: Hi Aamir. If I edit the computed values in Google Chrome when inspecting the element, that does seem to size the image more accurately. What is this telling me though?

Comment: after u edit html changes too just copy paste it in ur page or u can see what is changing